# Forcesorting, then disabling sort using jQuery Tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have this table that I am sorting with [tablsorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). I want to force sort the C, but I also want to make that row not clickable by the user. (meaning tablesorter force sorts on this row, then the user can't touch it.)

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my tablesorter code:

```
params = {
          sortList: [[2, 0]]
          , headers: {
              0: { sorter: false },
              1: { sorter: 'text' },
              2: { sorter: 'text' },
          }
          }
          , sortForce: [[2,0]] 
};
```

When i set row 2 to : `2: { sorter: false }`, I get an exception. I think this exception is because my `sortList` is set to `[[2,0]]`, my sortFroce is set to `[[2,0]]`, but setting row 2 to, `'false'`. --Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember an issue with `sortForce` not working correctly, but I can't seem to find it in the [change log](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki/Change), except back in version 2.0.2.

Either way, it should be fixed in my fork of [tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) on github. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/32/) I put together (I left out the `sortList` option so you can see the last column sort.